# Increment iterator over end of the list

Tags: c++

I have noticed that when you increment iterator over the end of the list and than decrement it, it goes back to the end of the list:

```
list<int> ls = {1, 2, 3, 4};
list<int>::iterator it;
it = ls.end();
it++;it++;it++;
it--;it--;it--;it--;
cout << *it << endl; // prints 4
```

How can it be implemented to do so?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. If you are curious about implementation details, the source code for the standard library came with your compiler.

Comment: You are breaking the language rules (invoking undefined behaviour). *Any* behaviour by your compiler is acceptable - warning you, crashing your program, removing your code, doing what you happen to expect, formatting your harddrive, *anything*. You've left the realm of valid C++ where you have guarantees about behaviour. Your program is simply broken.

Comment: A simple way this could work (and I've certainly seen this in the past) is that the list could  actually be a circular list under the hood. (please don't rely on this though)

Comment: Try it with a few different compilers, with a few different optimization settings, on a few different operating systems and you'll quickly find that you get lots of different results, because what you are doing is *not* valid C++, but [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: It is *possible* that your compiler 'optimizes away' the three `++` and three of the `--` operations. But I' **not** suggesting this is anything but undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AdrianMole: I doubt it, Whereas `operator++` and `operator--` has **logical** meaning for human, for compiler, it is as `f(); f(); f(); g(); g(); g(); g();` whereas there are no logic to discard pair. Especially with `list::iterator` with pointer manipulation with `prev`/`next`, How can we know that `node == node->next->prev`?

Comment: @Jarod42 Basically, I essentially agree. But a *really* smart compiler, with an efficient implementation of the `std::list::iterator`, could make some shrewd deductions, in this particular case. But, whatever else is happening, there ***is*** UB!!